# Oracle Critical Patch Updates download

Tags: oracle

I know that Oracle Critical Patch Updates are reachable from "https://support.oracle.com", but somehow I can't access it. Is there any other place to download that?

Comment: Patches are only available to organisations which pay Oracle for a Support license.  If you don't pay for Oracle Support then you can't get patches; simple as that. Supposing you do work for a licensee then somebody can set you up with Oracle Support access. Usually the DBAs manage the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's none, as far as I know.

What do you mean, "somehow" you can't access it? It requires username/password and lets you in, but you can't do anything (such as download files you need) unless you **pay** licence fees to Oracle for software you use. So, do you pay (a lot) of money to Oracle? If not, you won't be able to do what you meant to.